# Data trending decision criteria

Tags: trend, finance, games

I'm playing a game in which you can buy and sell items (it's an mmorpg). Now, after certain events, there is a huge drop in the price of certain items (there is a seasonal double experience weekend in which many people grind a lot, causing the market to overflow with certain items). Now, I want to decide which items I could buy right after that double experience weekend to sell a month after. 
I have the average price of the item per day readily available (I downloaded all the data to my computer) and it can look for example like this:
[image]

As you can see, there is a huge drop around the beginning of october after which it will steadily raise again. I only have the data of one of those double experience weekends though...
Now, my question is: how can I decide whether an item is a good one to buy in a (semi-)automatic way. Are there any good criteria? I want to calculate a 'score' of an item to decide whether it's a good one or not (let's say that every item is always traded and there is always a sufficient amount of offer and demand).
At the moment, I'm looking if a price of an items drops during the days after the double experience weekend and compare it to the price a month later. This still has some errors though, because some items do not respond as fast as other (in their drop).
Any theories I should be looking at? Any criteria to investigate? Keep in mine I want to buy DURING the double experience weekend and sell about a month after.

Thanks for your time already!

PS: I also don't know if this is the correct section for my question...

Comment: Make a histogram of "profits within 30 days" with bins similar to {[-2000, -1000],...[5000, 6000]}, using the whole dataset of price histories. Select the profitable ones and then make another histogram with these according to item class (sword,  armor etc.), and then if possible by "selling player ID" to see who sells for cheap ( and other features if you like). You'll get insights from these sorts of histograms.

Comment: Thanks for your comment already. The point however is that the range of the different items is not similar (some items might be worth millions, while others are worth within the hundreds range). Additionally, the different items have a buy limit every day (to avoid heavy merchen of items).
So I would like to find a criteria that can be calculated based on the data to finally produce a list of the 'most profitable items'. I don't want to investigate every item manually. Otherwise, I can just look at the graphs ^^.

Answer (score 0):

How about, form a table using the data with 2 columns A and B. A contains the item ID and B contains $mean(p(t_0+25:t_0+35))-p(t_0)$. Sort by column B. Pick the top N entries, where N is the number of trades allowable.

Here,  $p (t_0)$ is the weekend low price.

Comment: It's a bit like what I initially did (compare with the price a month after), but this idea is better than just to pick precisely 30 days after. I quite like it. And multiply the answer with the buy limit to see the absolute profit. Will give a better insight indeed!

Comment: I don't think there's anyway you can get around the assumption "the future will mimic the past" in the absence of additional research or assumptions. There might be certain fads that led to price rises one weekend that won't in the next. It depends on the game. I think it's good to understand your data by, say, plotting all the short-sword item histories on one plot and seeing if all in a price range have the same price trend. Question aside, it would be interesting to see what happens the next weekend. Post the results if you can :)

Comment: I like how you think, because that's the first thing one would do and this was more or less the basis of my thinking (but from a slightly different point). However, as I guess you have no insight in the game (runescape), you might not see all the information. Several items of the same class are for example not worth working with in this dexp weekend due to their bad price/experience ratio. But what I did was to investigate some items with a good price/experience ratio of which I'm 100% sure people produce a lot (of which the one in the graph is an example) and then base myself of that.

Comment: Previous comment continued: additionally, you're right that the assumption "the future will mimic the past" is not always right. Especially not because a new skill was recently released in the game (with a huge impact on the prices, so nobody knows for sure the reaction on the market after this dexp weekend). But as I obviously only have this data, I can only base myself on this and thus I HAVE to assume the same will happen. Good point though!

Comment: Wow, they have quite a detailed database http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/

Comment: They do, but they only go 6 months back (other sites go back further in time, but make scraping not possible)... And to analyze, I have to download that data first which is of course not readily available ^^.